# Free TFS team process templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, alm

Anybody knows custom or free available process templates for TFS 2010? Right now, I have only 2 default templates with Server. I am looking for couple of other templates too.

Comment: Is there some specific functionality you desire that isn't provided in the 2 default templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the default [MSF Agile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd380647%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [CMMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997574%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) templates, Microsoft also released the popular [Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=197304) and [MSF-Agile plus Security Development Lifecycle (SDL)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25082).